# greeting the wife of a colleague with 「お世話になっています」?

Tags: usage

Supposing I'm meeting a colleague's wife for the first time, I was trying to think of how to modify いつもお世話になっています to express something like "I'm always in your husband's care". Is this appropriate? if so, how would I modify the phrase?

I've encountered the phase used where the speaker is thanking the person he's talking to on behalf of a third person - for example 息子がお世話になっています - and I wondered if it works the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say to her:

> 「いつもご[主人]{しゅじん}[に]お[世話]{せわ}になっております。」=  "I'm always in your husband's care".

Do not forget the honorific ご.　The に can be replaced with には without changing the meaning.

She would say to you:

> 「いつも主人[が]お世話になっております。」=  "My husband is always in your care."

She will not use the ご because it is her own husband.

Finally, it is always the particle that can change the meaning of the sentence entirely.  In this case, it is に vs. が.

(If you usually did not speak all that politely or humbly, you could replace the おります part with います, but you could never omit that ご.)

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> [私は]ご主人にいつもお世話になっております。
> 〜"I'm always in your husband's care"
> (I am sure you can come up with an appropriate English equivalent.　The [ ]= unspoken.)

The following examples from the Apple dictionary illustrate the grammar for the expression 世話になる

> 息子はその婦人にたいへんお世話になった｜My son owes that woman a great deal.
>
> 伯父には金銭上の世話になった｜I had financial help from my uncle.

Comment: 「私は」 in that greeting is not even optional. It is just not used.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya: The square brackets around [私は] were intended to indicate this part was unspoken. Correct me if I am wrong but I think it is grammatically correct (if it is not then this common misunderstanding among us learners).